# sort mysql results

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i want improve my search page

i am using this query to search in posts by post title or post content

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE post_title rlike $this->secure($_GET['p_title']) 
  OR post_content rlike $this->secure($_GET['p_title']);
```

i want sort posts

i want to print posts that i got by `post_title` first

and then print the posts that i got by `post_content`

should i use two querys to sort them? and if so. How to merge two mysql querys?

Comment: @sirko, i can't accept any answer before at lest 10 mins, second i am trying your answer..

Comment: The comment was not concerning this question, but more general. You have only accepted 6 answers out of 10 questions, which is a quiet low ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge the results of two queries using the `UNION` operator ([Docu link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)) like the following:

```
( SELECT 0 AS toBeOrdered, * FROM posts 
  WHERE post_title rlike $this->secure($_GET['p_title'])  )
UNION
( SELECT 1 AS toBeOrdered, * FROM posts 
  WHERE post_content rlike $this->secure($_GET['p_title']) )
ORDER BY toBeOrdered ASC
```

I inserted a column `toBeOrdered` to reflect your desired sorting.

Answer (score 0):

try using the [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) statement

Answer (score 0):

You can sort multiple columns with the following syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE post_title rlike $this->secure($_GET['p_title']) 
OR post_content rlike $this->secure($_GET['p_title'])
ORDER BY post_title ASC, post_content DESC
```

Of course, adjust ASC and DESC accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can sort arrays using PHP with `usort` (user sort) which can sort an array with a given comparison function. In order to do that, you first have to create a function that can compare two posts according to their titles and another one that can compare their contents.

You can alternatively use SQL to sort it in the query with `ORDER BY`, it's simple to code and also faster when loading the web page. The number 1 rule when using PHP/MySQL is: what can be done by MySQL should be done by MySQL.

To answer your last question: don't merge your queries, they'll be mixed up and you will then have to separate them with PHP. Two queries aren't that bad, you know!